# How to replace "Planned" with "Actuals" if the data exists using SQL

Tags: sql, filtering, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like this.

WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE:

| DATE | MOVIE | LOCATION | TYPE | VIEWS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/19/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned |  |
| 11/26/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 35 |
| 12/3/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 20 |
| 12/10/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 20 |
| 12/10/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 45 |
| 12/17/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 30 |
| 12/17/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 53 |
| 12/24/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 40 |
| 12/24/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 55 |
| 12/31/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 40 |
| 12/31/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 64 |
| 1/7/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 70 |
| 1/7/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 75 |
| 1/14/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 30 |
| 1/14/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 54 |
| 1/21/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 10 |
| 1/21/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 15 |
| 1/28/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 10 |
| 1/28/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals |  |
| 2/4/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 14 |

I want to only include Planned if Actuals doesn't exist. What should I try? The actuals row could exist but with a 0. It should only show actuals if that value is > 0

EXPECTED:

| DATE | MOVIE | LOCATION | TYPE | VIEWS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/19/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned |  |
| 11/26/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 35 |
| 12/3/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 20 |
| 12/10/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 45 |
| 12/17/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 53 |
| 12/24/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 55 |
| 12/31/2020 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 64 |
| 1/7/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 75 |
| 1/14/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 54 |
| 1/21/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Actuals | 15 |
| 1/28/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 10 |
| 2/4/2021 | SUPERMAN | NEW YORK | Planned | 14 |

Answer (score 1):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'Actuals' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date = t.date and
                        t2.movie = t.movie and
                        t2.location = t.location and
                        t2.type = 'Actuals'
                 );
```

A fun way is to use aggregation:

```
select date, movie, location,
       coalesce( max(case when type = 'Actuals' then type end),
                 max(type)
               ) as type,
       coalesce( max(case when type = 'Actuals' then views end),
                 max(views)
               ) as views
from t
group by date, movie, location;
```

But the most common way would use `qualify` with a window function:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by date, movie, location
                           order by type
                          ) = 1;
```

Note:  The ordering is alphabetical and `'Actuals' < 'Planned'`.